# How to check for at least one regex

Tags: php, regex

I can verify a string if respects this format "XXw XXd XXh XXm" by using the following Regex :

`(\d{1}|\d{2})w (\d{1}|\d{2})d (\d{1}|\d{2})h (\d{1}|\d{2})m`

XX : are integers

I want to be able to check if at least one of XXw, XXd, XXh, XXm is present in the string, any way to do it via Regex ?

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? Create a new regex to check if a string has 1 or 2 digits followed by the 4 letters as in the regex you have? [`(?<=\D|^)\d{1,2}[wdhm]\b` with `preg_match`](http://ideone.com/RhC6hI)?

Comment: `XXw XXd XXh XXm` just guessing, *week*, *day*, *hour*, *minute* ? Sure you want a RegExp rather than a `DateTime()` object?

Comment: yes its week, day, hour, minute. I'm not converting the string to any other format, just check if valid and send it to JIRA via API to track issues time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=.*?\d{1,2}[wdhm])
```

You can add a simple `lookahead` to check that.